# Group structs by exploding map<struct> into a list and filtering with sameElement

Tags: vespa

Can vespa group on `<map: string,struct>` with a clause on `struct.k1=x` AND `struct.k2=y` and only getting the counts with how many structs match (not documents!, cause a document may have multiple structs that match) ?

So it will explode all `struct` in a list using `where struct.k1=x AND struct.k2=y` and return a group of map.

Just like you can filter with `sameElement`, in this case you list the structs, do a `sameElement` filter, and then group by `struct.k3`

Does that make sense ? 
Thank you

edit: an example is in Postgresql. `unnest()` can be used on `array` while `json_each()` can be used on `json` to convert them to row
Reference:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vespa's grouping framework will work on the all the map elements in the document and not only the ones that matched the sameElement query item. Similar if you have a simple `field foo array<string>{}` grouping will operate over all elements in the array and not only the element(s) which matched the query.